# How to display a dropdown menu without grouping name

Tags: usability, buttons, menu, dropdown

Here is how my menu is looking at the moment.
[image]

It is a list of dropdown/buttons. When I click on a options in the dropdown it will display some content. I can also click on the dropdown itself to display the content of the item shown.

The dropdown does not have name thus it is the first item which is shown.

Is there a better way to create this menu ?

Comment: Where is this menu used in your app/site? What kind of content do the options link to? If you are able to group the content, why can't you name the grouping?

Comment: The menu is placed on top of the website and will be available in every views. It can be hidded/showed. Every options displays different data on a map or open a new link. It is an old website, I didnt group them my self and it is hard to give them a understable name

Comment: I see. How about you update the question with each menu item and what it does? This way, someone with Information Architecture expertise can give some advice on naming the groups and possibly reordering them. As the question stands, there isn't enough information to point you to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what you need to indicate what the drop down list is for! Either inside the drop down box or above/beside it. So if all the drop downs are for "Favorite TV Shows" you should have that written at the top-center of the page, otherwise you should add a unique one above each drop down. If that takes up too much space, you need to have it inside the the drop down itself.

I hope you find a solution to what you are implementing! Good luck!